# GWT and web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, servlets

I'm trying to learn GWT. I'm used to seeing servlet entries in web.xml file. I saw some GWT project samples having no entries in web.xml and it still work. What's going on? As far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong, there's no way you could programmatically set servlet mappings until servlet 3.0. My question is, how does GWT work without having to configure any servlets at all in web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The examples or samples you have seen, perhaps do not have any server side code. 
GWT when compiled is all javascript code.
Server-side code usually goes under server package ( there are 3 packages - 
client - all Views and UI widgets , 
shared - classes that will be shared between UI and Server, typically DTO
server - all server side components. ( proxy / async proxy and proxyImpl ) - extends RemoteServiceServlet

If there was a server side component, those proxies would have to be mentioned within web.xml
More info here , under "Creating services" -> http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html