# Default resource for root context

Tags: servlets

Given is that there are no entries in welcome-file-list in web.xml. What resource the servlet container should try to look for if the request URL only contains the root context, e.g. `localhost:8080/myWebApp` and which part of the servlet specification (any version less than 3.0) does it say so? It seems that it looks for "index.html" if nothing is specified in the welcome-file-list.

**Update:**

Here's the entire web.xml generated by the maven archetype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

And here's the maven archetype I used to generate the web app:

```
254: remote -> net.sf.mgp:maven-archetype-gwt (An archetype which contains a sample Maven GWT project.)
```

I tried visiting the root context of the app and it served the /index.html resource and served the page with a button. It didn't give a 404.

Comment: why do you think it's looking for index.html?

Comment: @John 2 I tried running a gwt sample project and had no clue how did the servlet container knew that it needed to serve index.html. I made a question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414513/gwt-and-web-xml

Comment: what is your container/server?

Comment: I tried it on both Jboss 7.1.1 and tomcat 5.5. Got same results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Servlet spec doesn't say anything about this. If your web application doesn't mention a welcome-file list and your context-root is myWebApp then when you hit

```
localhost:8080/myWebApp
```

You will get **HTTP 404** error.

Comment: I tried creating an almost blank simple web app, with nothing in the web.xml but headers and an index.html file. Nope, it really doesn't give HTTP 404 if you have index.html file or index.jsp file. I think I can safely say this answer is wrong. I tested using Jboss 5.1/7.1.1, Tomcat 5.5.

Comment: then it's a feature of the server not servlet spec

Comment: if it's just a server specific feature, why would the authors of the archetypes assumed there's no need to specify anything in the web.xml? That would make their archetypes non-portable.